# Probabilty of Arizona being hit by a wild fire at least once in ten years

Tags: probability

What is the probability that Arizona will be hit by a wild fire at least once in the next ten years, considering an average of 1653.7 wildfires occur each year in Arizona? I am unsure of the exact formula, and what other information to look for....What i do know is that Arizona has wildfires frequently so it must me high I'm guessing? Please help !!!

Comment: Without any calculations, I guess it is 99.9999%......

Comment: This wiki may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Being sure of an exact formula will help tremendously, as without it there is not enough information to answer.  We can make *assumptions* about the formula, for example that it follows a [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), however that is a rather strong assumption.  Maybe there is a 99.999% chance that no fires occur in a given year versus an 0.001% chance that a billion fires occur in a given year... On the other hand maybe there is a 100% chance of at least one fire a year since someone intentionally sets one yearly.  both give different results.

Comment: I think the formula would be .... P(hit at least once)= 1-P(not hit at all)

Comment: But that is what i do not understand.... if Arizona is hit with wildfires frequently.... how would you find or look up information for Arizona not being hit at all.... if that makes sense.